# Runtime of for loop

Tags: for-loop, runtime

What's the runtime for this nested for loop in big O notation?

```
for(i = 1 to k)
{
    for(j = i+1 to k)
    {}
}
```

It's smaller than O(k^2) but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is closely related to the series sum *S(k) = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + (k-2) + (k-1)*.  It can be shown that *S(k) = (k*(k-1))/2 = (k*k)/2 - k/2.*  [How?  Reorder the sum as *S(k) = {0+(k-1)} + {1+(k-2)} + {2+(k-3)} + ....*  This shows how.]

Therefore, *is* the algorithmic order smaller than *O(k*k)?*  Remember that constant coefficients like *1/2* do not influence the big O notation.

*Question:*  So it's equivalent to replacing `j = i+1 to k` with `j = 1 to k`?

*Answer:*  Right.  This is tricky, so let's think it through. For `i == 1`, how many times does the inner loop's action run? Answer: it runs `k-1` times. Again, for `i == 2`, how many times does the inner loop's action run? Answer: it runs `k-2` times. Ultimately, for `i == k`, how many times does the inner loop's action run? Answer: it runs zero times. Therefore, over all values of `i`, how many times does the inner loop's action run?  Answer: `(k-1) + (k-2) + ... + 0`, which is just the aforementioned sum *S(k)*.

Comment: So it's equivalent to replacing j = i+1 with j = 1?

Comment: No.  This is tricky, but let's think it through.  For `i == 1`, how many times does the inner loop's action run?  Answer:  it runs `k-1` times.  Again, for `i == 2`, how many times does the inner loop's action run?  Answer:  it runs `k-2` times.  Ultimately, for `i == k`, how many times does the inner loop's action run?  Answer:  it runs zero times.  Therefore, over all values of `i`, how many times does the inner loop's action run?  Answer:  `(k-1) + (k-2) + ... + 0`, which is just the aforementioned sum *S(k)*.

Comment: I meant it's equivalent in terms of time complexity. Since both give O(k^2) bounds. where j = i+1 gives O(k*(k-1)/2 = O(k^2) and j = 1 is O(k*(k+1)/2) = O(k^2)

Comment: I see.  That's right.  You wouldn't think it, but using j = i+1 instead of j = 1 eliminates about half of the invocations of the inner loop's action, but it doesn't eliminate much more than that; so you are correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda non-intuitive. Thanks!